# Show Lagrangian of a three-spring problem

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider two equal masses of mass $m$. There are three springs attached horizontally to the two masses: the first mass has equilibrium at $x_1$ and is attached to the left wall (where $x=0$) by a spring with spring constant $k$. the second mass has equilibrium at $x_2$ and is attached to the first mass by a spring with spring constant $k_0$ and to the right wall by a spring with spring constant $k$. Derive the Lagrangian of this mass-spring system, which should be

$$ L = \frac{m}{2}\left(\dot{x_1}^2+\dot{x_2}^2\right)-\frac{k}{2}\left( x_1^2+x_2^2 \right) -\frac{k_0}{2} \left( x_2 -x_1 \right)^2.$$

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be to generalized coordinates. Then $\vec{x} = x_1\hat{x_1}+x_1\hat{x_2}$. Thus $\vec{v}=\dot{\vec{x}}=\dot{x_1}\hat{x_1}+\dot{x_2}\hat{x_2}$. So $(KE)=\frac{m}{2}\left(\dot{x_1}^2+\dot{x_2}^2\right)$. So this part is OK.

It becomes very confusing with the potential energy. $\vec{F}=\vec{\nabla}U=-kx_1\hat{x_1}+kx_2\hat{x_2}-k_0 x_2\hat{x_2}+k_0x_1\hat{x_1}$ (please correct me if I'm wrong). Now, $(PE)$ comes out to be
$$ (PE) = \frac{k}{2}\left(x_2^2 - x_1^2 \right) + \frac{k_0}{2}\left( x_1^2 + x_2^2 \right), $$ which is not what I need. So something is apparently wrong.

I'd appreciate some input.

Comment: Please look at this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016049/show-lagrangian-of-a-three-spring-problem

Comment: @caverac this is the link to exactly this thread.

Comment: My apologies, this is the link http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174760/lagrangian-kinetic-potential-energy-with-two-masses-connected-to-three-spring

Comment: @caverac The linked post on the physics site is no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the change of variables

$$
y_1+y_2+y_3 = l_0\\
\delta y_1+\delta y_2+\delta y_3 = 0\\
\delta y_1=\delta x_1\\
\delta y_1+\delta y_2 = \delta x_2
$$

and also

$$
T = \frac 12   m\left(\dot{\delta  x_1}^2+\dot{\delta  x_2}^2\right)\\
V = \frac 12\left(k \delta y_1^2+k_0 \delta y_2^2+k \delta y_3^2 \right)
$$

after substitution we obtain

$$
L = T - V = \frac 12   m\left(\dot{ \delta x_1}^2+\dot{ \delta x_2}^2\right)-\frac 12\left(k (\delta x_1^2+\delta x_2^2)+k_0 (\delta x_2-\delta x_1)^2 \right)
$$